# MariaDB "Data truncated for column" message on a column not involved in query

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariasql

I am doing a simple update query as follows:

```
UPDATE table SET column0 = CONCAT('0x', LPAD(HEX(column1), 4, '0')) WHERE column2 LIKE 'A%';
```

The datatype of column0 is varchar.

This gives me the error:

> "Data truncated for column 'column3' at row 1"

Usually, this is simple, column0 has the wrong datatype, but note that the error message is complaining about a column that I am not updating nor querying from. How could this be? I executed a similar query just before this query, setting the value of a varchar column to `CONCAT(...)` and it worked as expected.

Comment: Your information tells us NOTHING about the actual column sizes. What the heck does `column0` have to do with the truncated data at `column3`??? ... is there a trigger or some other stored procedure involved?

Comment: The question states column0 is varchar. “What the heck does column0 have to do with column3” is exactly my question.

Comment: Ok, so show the table definition, we have no way to tell, cannot read your DB schema from here. (I also edited my previous comment) ... and `varchar` what? 1, 2, 500 ???

Comment: You comment edit put me on the right track, it was a trigger

Comment: No problem, that's why details are important here, but no worries! Glad you found the root cause.

Comment: Certainly a major “duh” moment for me. Although maybe a feature request to have the error message display the table name along with the errant column would prevent public brain farts like this in the future